# Jquery zoom with a clickable element that doesn't disrupt functionality

Tags: jquery, css

I am building a game where someone has to search for a small image within a photo using this JQuery zoom plugin: http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom.htm

When the user finds this element it needs to be clickable to trigger a function. All pretty straightforward except that when the user hovers over this element it disrupts the zoom functionality which gives the game away. Can anyone tell me a way to embed a clickable element within this zoom image that doesn't disrupt the flow of the zoom.

I've hashed together an example here:

http://christophercamplin.com/zoom/

Any help here much appreciated.

Comment: The device is right in the centre of the image btw.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an onclick setup similar to this.
only instead of just shooting off a box, check if their coordinates are in the correct area, if yes, do what you must, if no then do nothing.  This gets rid of need for the a tag that causes problems.

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript">
function dog(){
alert("start");
pig.onclick=function(e){
alert(e.pageX+"dg"+e.pageY);
};
alert("done");
}
</script>
<title>your face</title>
</head>
<body onload="dog();">
<div style="display:block; width:200px; height:200px; background-color:Red;" id=pig>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My javascript knowledge isn't excellent but i can't seem to solve my problem using the above code, could you possibly elaborate further with how i could set the position for the click ?